# What is a word that can be used like "socialist," but for capitalism?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Those who support the ideology of socialism are called "socialists".

However, those who support the ideology of capitalism are not called "capitalists". Instead, those who own capital are called capitalists.

Is there a word I can use to describe those who support the ideology of capitalism?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *capitalist*. The premise of your question is faulty.

While it's true that the word *can* mean someone who owns capital, that's only *one* sense of the definition of the word.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capitalist):

> noun
> **2** : a person who favors capitalism
>
> adjective
> **2 a** : practicing or advocating capitalism
> // *capitalist* nations
> **2 b** :  marked by capitalism
> // *capitalist* period of history

Note, too, the definition of [**capitalism**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capitalism):

> : an economic system characterized by private or corporate ownership of capital goods, by investments that are determined by private decision, and by prices, production, and the distribution of goods that are determined mainly by competition in a free market

As with any word that has more than one meaning, context determines the meaning in any particular case.

Comment: The thing is, whenever I call someone from history a "capitalist" because they supported capitalism, other people are quick to say things like "they didn't own any capital though."

Comment: It's certainly unusual for somebody who is a capitalist to not own anything. But owning something isn't a requirement of being a capitalist in the sense of believing in the economic theory. (A homeless person, down on their luck, could be a capitalist. Even if, given their situation, it would be better for them if they met socialists.)